# python pathlib operator '/' - how does it do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I found the pathlib syntax - or is it the Python syntax - surprising. I'd like to know how this makes the forward slash `/` act as a joiner of `WindowsPath`s etc. Does it override/overload `/` ?  It seems to be in a magical context, the slash is between a `WindowsPath` type object and a string. If I try between 2 strings it fails to join the 2 strings (e.g.  `"123" / "123"` fails)

```
p=pathlib.Path(".")

p
Out[66]: WindowsPath('.')

p.cwd()
Out[67]: WindowsPath('C:/Users/user1')

p.cwd() / "mydir"
Out[68]: WindowsPath('C:/Users/user1/mydir')
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The Path class has a [`__truediv__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) method that returns another Path. You can do the same with your own classes:

```
>>> class WeirdThing(object):
        def __truediv__(self, other):
            return 'Division!'

>>> WeirdThing() / WeirdThing()
'Division!'
```

Comment: Thanks, the code you mention seems to start on line 894 in pathlib.py     -----      def __truediv__(self, key):
        return self._make_child((key,))  - although I don't think I would ever override '/' to do anything.

Comment: is this considered 'unpythonic' ? It feels to me like predictable behaviour has been neglected here

Comment: @BenJones Personally, I would like it if `Path() + Path()` or `Path() + 'path'` concatenated the path strings while `Path() / Path()` or `Path() / 'path'` `os.path.join`ed them, but the way it currently is isn't unpythonic per se IMO.

Comment: What's going on here though? the class 'object' doesn't have a __truediv__ method that get's overridden. What ties this method to the '/' symbol?

Comment: @Andrew When evaluating `a / b`, Python attempts to call `a.__truediv__(b)` under the hood. If it is not present (or returns `NotImplemented`), then it tries `b.__rtruediv__(a)`. If that fails, it raises a `TypeError`. What ties the method to the `/` operator is Python itself. Whether or not the method is implemented in a parent class has no bearing on whether it can be defined in a subclass.

Comment: Answering myself, the __truediv__ dunder method  is documented in the refence documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations
as well as other dunder methods for addition, subtraction, multiplication and modulo.

Answer (score 6):

For whoever wants to see the source code briefly:

`__truediv__` overload the `/` operator, and returns `self`, which is a `Path` object.

```
    # this is where the magic begins! (overload the '/' operator)
    def __truediv__(self, key): 
        try:
            return self._make_child((key,))
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented


    def _make_child(self, args):
        drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
        drv, root, parts = self._flavour.join_parsed_parts(
            self._drv, self._root, self._parts, drv, root, parts)
        return self._from_parsed_parts(drv, root, parts)


    @classmethod
    def _from_parsed_parts(cls, drv, root, parts):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self._drv = drv
        self._root = root
        self._parts = parts
        return self  # finally return 'self', which is a Path object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works by overriding a **dunder method** traditionally dedicated to division.
In the same way, the first time I saw a matrix multiplication with the `@` operator, I was stunned and after some research found out it was using a dunder method under the hood, `__matmul__` (as often in Python), except this time judging by its name it was made for that.

So, you could create a class that overrides a lot of operators (e.g. ^, &, @, |, ^=, &=, @=, |=, etc.) and use them for purposes other than their original purpose, although that may not be the best practice.