# What is / in python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering about / in python.

I know that it divides two integers, but I've seen something like this

```
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'
```

Comment: For a `Path` from `pathlib` the `/` operator is overwritten and joins both sides into a new path.

Comment: In Python, any type can define their own functionality for the action of operators. Probably, just guessing by the context, these are `pathlib.Path` objects

Comment: Related: [python pathlib operator '/' - how does it do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53083963/4518341)

Comment: not sure why this got linked to an eclipse question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python allows defining the behaviour of operators when applied to custom classes using specially named methods ("dunders", from "double-underline"), as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). The `/` operator's behaviour can be defined by `.__truediv__(self, other)` method. It is almost certainly the case here that `BASE_DIR` is an instance of `pathlib.Path`, which defines `/` as semantically equivalent to `os.path.join` for strings. You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators).

Answer (score 0):

`BASE_DIR` is `pathlib.Path` object which supports the `/` operator for joining paths. You need to either use `/` or use `os.path.join` if you use strings.